# Tomboy is reporting an error when I try to sync to Ubuntu One, but isn't giving an error message

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy

Whenever I try to sync my Tomboy notes with Ubuntu One, I get the following window:

[image]

From the non-message presented here I have no idea what do to to troubleshoot this problem. I've tried unistalling and reinstalling the Ubuntu One app and the problem persists. My next option would be to do the same with Tomboy itself, but I'm unsure what will happen to my notes if I do that. Is it a good idea to try reinstalling Tomboy, or is there another way to go about fixing this.

NB: I think this happened when I reinstalled my system without formatting my drive after 10.10 came out, and something was perhaps broken in the process.

Comment: You should file a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close tomboy and start it again from a terminal in debug mode:-

```
tomboy --debug
```

You'll probably find you get a more detailed error message form the terminal. I've found this very helpful in debugging issues. If you need more help, just paste the relavent fragment of the log here and we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply run cat /home/user/.config/tomboy/tomboy.log  from a terminal. Very sadly, there are several bugs in tomboy in Ubuntu 11.10 since this is such a great app. Yours might be related to this one [Tomboy Notes: Failed to synchronize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71733/tomboy-notes-failed-to-synchronize)