# Tomboy Notes: Failed to synchronize

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync, tomboy

In my new ubuntu 11.10 install the Tomboy notes synchronizes just some of my notes notes and then fails. The details only shows the updated notes. When I look at the .config/tomboy/tomboy.log I see the error:

```
10/24/2011 11:12:29 PM [ERROR]: Synchronization failed with the following exception: A note with this title already exists: New Note Template
  at Tomboy.NoteManager.CreateNewNote (System.String title, System.String xml_content, System.String guid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tomboy.NoteManager.CreateNoteFromTemplate (System.String title, Tomboy.Note template_note, System.String guid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tomboy.NoteManager.CreateNewNote (System.String title, System.String guid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tomboy.NoteManager.CreateWithGuid (System.String title, System.String guid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager+<CreateNoteInMainThread>c__AnonStorey11.<>m__3F () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tomboy.GuiUtils+<GtkInvokeAndWait>c__AnonStoreyC.<>m__2F (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have tryed changing the URL on the sync preferences to `https://edge.one.ubuntu.com/notes/` as sugested in question 66753 but it did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if I am supposed to answer my own question but I have managed to solve the problem.

Since the error on the log mentioned a note named "New Note Template" I created a note with that name through the ubuntu one web site and then tried to sync again. This time tomboy detected the conflict and offered some options to solve it. I chose to rename the local note and then it synced all my notes correctly!

Comment: Do you mind posting this bug on launchpad? Sadly, this is not the only tomboy related bug in Ubuntu 11.10 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/883370 / http://askubuntu.com/questions/73429/does-tomboy-break-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: I have added a comment on a bug that I believe is the same I got: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/848250

Answer (score 1):

Thanks 'lpanebr'  for the reference to change server address in Tomboy Preferences to:

https://edge.one.ubuntu.com/notes/  note the addition 'edge' to the address

Sync proceeded OK.

Comment: This is not my merit. It goes to http://askubuntu.com/questions/71733/tomboy-notes-failed-to-synchronize/71882 thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I opened the Tomboy Preferences, and on the first tab (Editing), clicked "New Note Template". I then renamed the Template title to "Title" instead of "New Note Template". Then closed this template note, and synchronization worked.