# Does Tomboy break Unity / Compiz?

Tags: unity, tomboy

I tested it with a Ubuntu 11.10 Live CD x64 and a fresh install on my HDD:

After starting Tomboy I cannot logout / shutdown / restart anymore. The menu bar / launcher disappears after initiating the logout but the Desktop background won't disappear. Windows remain open but do loose their window decorations...

Tested with Unity 2D / 3D.

Running Ubuntu on a Toshiba P835 with Intel HD 3000, so it would be great if somebody could confirm this, before I can post this to launchpad.

Edit: Since it was confirmed I opened a bug on launchpad: [bug #883370](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/883370). Please vote to get this fixed soon!

Edit2:

There are bugs already related to my problem at bugzilla

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650029

and launchpad

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/880299

Closed.

Comment: Posted to Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/883370

Comment: And that, in turn, has been marked as a duplicate of [bug 880299](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/880299).

Comment: Vote to close as this is a bug and we can do anything here to help you with bugs (if there's a workaround this should go in the bug report).

Comment: Sure, go ahead and close it.

Answer (score 2):

I have done a quick test with Ubuntu 11.10 32bit on my spare laptop (Toshiba Tecra A8).  This machine was updated about 8 hours ago with all updates (including oneiric-proposed).

Just as you indicate, when Tomboy is running if I then go to "Logout" it seems to initiate but then "hangs" with Unity closing but the windows of all open apps staying open but losing decoration.  Thanks for spotting this as my main machine isn't running Oneiric yet and I rely on tomboy!

UPDATE: as another user on launchpad indicates, logout is still possible, but it takes up to a minute after Unity disappears and all windows lose their decoration before the logout happens.  Subsequent login seems to have some random hangs.  I ended up rebooting before I had full functionality back (but again the machine "did" logout).